# HTML Canvas How can I get the rectangle to move backwards?

Tags: css, reactjs, html5-canvas

My code below animates a rectangle to grow right as soon as I start it. How can I make it simultaneously grow left? I have tried (line.x -= line.dx) and a few other variations and it does not seem to work.

```
   const line = {
        x: 600,
        y: 100,
        width: 1,
        height: 3,
        dx: 1,
        dy: 1,
    }

    let totalLineWidth = line.x + line.width;

    const drawLine = () => {
      ctx.fillRect(line.x, line.y , line.width, line.height)
    }


    const update = () => {

        drawLine()

        line.x += line.dx


    
        requestAnimationFrame(update)
    }
    update()
```

Answer (score 0):

At the same time as you draw a new bit to the right, draw a new bit to the left.

The new bit to the left goes an equal amount to the left as the new bit to the right. So that's (600 - (left.x - 600) - and of course update the 600 if you ever change the start position.

Run this snippet in full page and click the button to start the drawing.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const line = {
  x: 600,
  y: 100,
  width: 1,
  height: 3,
  dx: 1,
  dy: 1,
}

let totalLineWidth = line.x + line.width;

const drawLine = () => {
  ctx.fillRect(line.x, line.y, line.width, line.height);
  ctx.fillRect(600 - (line.x - 600), line.y, line.width, line.height);
}


const update = () => {

  drawLine()

  line.x += line.dx



  requestAnimationFrame(update)
}
//removed just for demo so we can wait until user clicks the button
//update()
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: pink;
  /* just for demo so we can see where the canvas is */
}
```

```html
<button onclick="update(); this.style.display = 'none';">Click me to start</button>
<br>
<canvas width=1200 height=200></canvas>
```

Comment: A follow up question, now how can I calculate when that left line hits the width to the left? I tried doing line.x -= line.dx and logging "hit" but it doesn't work. It seems as though having both line.x += line.dx and line.x -= line.dx counter each other. I need it to register 'hit' when either one hits the canvas.width.

Comment: This is so trivial I'm wondering whether I've understood correctly. Let me know if I've misinterpreted! It's just when you find yourself wanting to put the next drawing into a position <0. So it's when (600-(line.x - 600)) < 0

Comment: You actually solved my initial problem so thank you for that! But now, when I increment the line doing line.x += line.dx it only accounts for the right side. I a trying to detect collision on left aswell. 
            
 if(line.x  + line.width>  canvas.width) {
     console.log('right hit')
       }
  else if( (600 - (line.x -600)) <0){
      console.log('left hit')
       }
requestAnimationFrame(update)        }

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what the problem is - is there a problem? Are you hitting the right side before the left side for example.